# Solve for the general solution of this second-order question

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

So the equation is $y''+2y'+2y=\frac{1}{e^x cos(x)}$. It seems like I can solve this using Laplace transformations but I want to use another method. Can I use $y_h(x)+y_p(x)$, the trial solution, to solve this? But there's no trial solution for this question because it is a fraction. (Maybe I can write $\frac{1}{e^x cos(x)}$ as $(e^xcos(x))^{-1}$). But, I don't know how to go from here.

Comment: Are you sure that the task was not formulated with $e^{-x}\cos(x)$ on the right side? If not, then indeed the method of unknown coefficients does not apply, you would need variation of constants.

Comment: $y_p(x)=e^{-x}(\cos x \log{( \cos x) }+x \sin x)$

Comment: @AleksasDomarkas. Could you explain how you got this (exact) result ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the particular solution
$$y=e^{-x} z \implies z''+z=\sec(x)\implies \cos(x)z''+\cos(x) z=1$$
Now
$$z=\cos(x) u \implies \cos ^2(x) u''-2 \sin (x) \cos (x) u'=1$$
Reduction of order $$p=u' \implies \cos ^2(x) p'-2 \sin (x) \cos (x) p=1$$ which, now, is simple.

Comment: Now I understand how to get the particular solution, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Multiply your equation by $e^{(1+i)x}$ to get an exact one,
\begin{align}
e^{(1+i)x}y''+2e^{(1+i)x}y'+2e^{(1+i)x}y=\frac{2e^{ix}}{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}},
\end{align}
where I've used the complex representation of cosine, then integrate
\begin{align}
e^{(1+i)x}y'+\left(\frac{2}{1+i}\right)e^{(1+i)x}y=\ln|e^{ix}-1|-i\ln|e^{ix}+1|+c,\\
y'+\left(\frac{2}{1+i}\right)y=\Big(\ln|e^{ix}-1|-i\ln|e^{ix}+1|+c\Big)e^{(1+i)x}.
\end{align}
Which is a first order linear equation. Could you take it from here?